# Better way to find all elements with a class name

Tags: javascript

Is there a better/faster way to find all elements with a class name in browsers that don't support `document.getElementsByClassName`?

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    results = [];

for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  (elements[i].className === selector) ? results.push(elements[i]) : null;
}
return results;
```

And no I don't want to use jQuery :)

Comment: This doesn't actually get all the elements with the class, it gets the elements with *only* this class.

Comment: Hey! I never noticed that :) is there a way to find elements with the class?

Comment: @user494211 - Something like this: `for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) { if (" "+elements[i].className+" ".indexOf(" "+selector+" ") !== -1) results.push(elements[i]); }`

Comment: @NickCraver: borrowing jQuery's hasClass method, are we?

Comment: @OozeMeister that approach has been around for as long as I can remember, and well before jQuery...the jQuery implementation is [actually quite different](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c418b94eb48188cd9329519ae5e030a52dd81cc9/src/attributes/classes.js#L143).

Comment: nice, didn't know it was around that long. but they are basically the same code, just different flavor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would check out [John Resig's comparison](http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/) on methods for simulating `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 2):

While IE8 doesn't support `document.getElementsByClassName`, it does support `document.querySelectorAll`, so that would be an option for IE8 anyway.

You could do something like:

```
function byClass( sel ) {
    var results;
    if( document.querySelectorAll ) {
        results = document.querySelectorAll( '.' + sel );
    } else if( document.getElementsByClassName ) {
        results = document.getElementsByClassName( sel );
    } else {
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
        results = [];
        // and so on
    }
    return results;
}
```